# 1-to-many relationship with jpa 2.0 and GAE datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I am having problem understanding how to implement a 1-to-many unowned relationship on app engine. I am currently getting an exception that I trace back to an empty list.

```
@Entity
public class Inventory extends DatastoreObject {
    /**
     * List of all inventory items in this object.
     */
    @Unowned
    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems;
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting when trying to persist the entities.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A collection of values is required.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterPredicate.<init>(Query.java:847)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterOperator.of(Query.java:77)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.addFilter(Query.java:336)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.getChildrenByKeys(FKListStore.java:383)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.listIterator(FKListStore.java:360)
```

It appears that datanucleus is using a Filter IN query to fetch the InventoryItem child entities. The list is originally empty and contains no keys so this is breaking my retrieval.

Here is an exert from my persistence.xml file.

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes/>

<properties>
    <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.appengine.relationDefault" value="unowned" />
    <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: So the very odd thing happened. I change the List<InventoryItem> to use Set<InventoryItem> and it works correctly. What confuses me is that DataTypeUtils checks the type to see if it is instanceof Collection<?>. List extends Collection<?>. What is wrong or am I missing something.

Comment: I would like to have them as List so that I don't have to change my GWT editor code to use Set instead of List

Comment: GAE JPA has some simple tests for 1-N uni unowned in their SVN at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/test/jpa/UnownedJPAOneToManyUniListSideA.java?spec=svn935&r=935   so use that as a guide. It doesn't show any error at persist (but then you say you're persisting, yet present something from retrieval). FWIW "DataNucleus" doesn't do any query, since it is a third party library providing core facilities only; GAE JPA (developed by Google) is the plugin that does any calls to their datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I filed a bug with the GAE team to help shed some light on this. I changed my code to mirror your example but am still receiving this error. Which is odd because if I change it to use java.util.Set instead of java.util.List everything works fine. Here is a link to the bug if anyone else runs across this issue. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8019&thanks=8019&ts=1346028062

Comment: Their issue tracker for that software is at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/   You could also just download their current code, build it (mvn clean install) and try it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I built from source and the snapshot worked correctly. Looking at the logs it appears commit 936 fixed the problem. My list was null and this was causing the problem. Thanks again and I will update the bug with what I found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the collection

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Unowned
private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
```